# Trigger and Stored Procedure to Delete Old Values in MariaDB

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, mariadb

I have a table with a composite primary key, `id` and `code`, and a `value`.

```
CREATE TABLE `code_detail` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`code`),
  CONSTRAINT `code_detail_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `code_assignment` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `code_detail_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`code`) REFERENCES `code` (`code`)
)
```

It Looks like..

| id | code | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 30 |
| 1 | B | 70 |
| 2 | C | 50 |
| 2 | D | 50 |

The objective is to overwrite `where id = 2` with new codes and values. In doing so delete the old records.

| id | code | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 30 |
| 1 | B | 70 |
| 2 | E | 40 |
| 2 | F | 60 |

Currently, an insert statement looks like

```
INSERT INTO code_detail 
(id, code, value)
VALUES ((2, 'E', 50), (2, 'F', 50))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
value = VALUES(value)
```

You may notice that after this the resulting table would be

| id | code | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 30 |
| 1 | B | 70 |
| 2 | C | 50 |
| 2 | D | 50 |
| 2 | E | 40 |
| 2 | F | 60 |

This is undesired behavior. Records where the code is `C` and `D` should be removed.

I tried creating a trigger to check if the code(s) at old rows where `id = 2` are a subset of the new code(s) `((2, 'D', 50), (2, 'E', 50))`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_code_update 
AFTER INSERT ON code_detail
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF old.id = new.id AND old.code NOT IN (VALUES(new.code)) THEN
         CALL STORED_PROCEDURE(old.id, old.code);
     END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This raises an error: `Error Code: 1363. There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger`

Following through the logic despite the error...

If the old code(s) are **not** a subset then automatically delete them by calling a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_code(
    in_id INT, 
    old_code varchar(6)
)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM code_detail WHERE id = in_id AND code = old_code;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It could go from only a single old code to any number of codes where 'id = 2'. In whatever the case, the old code must be deleted if it is not a subset of the new codes being inserted.

Triggers and stored procedures aren't something I regularly encounter but given the nature of the problem and how the rest of the application works I think it's cause for trying out something like this. I may be wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

---

Additional Question: Does the trigger go through all rows in the `code_detail` table or is it only checking the rows where inserts were made? If it is the later, then the old records will be overlooked and the approach is not going to work.

Comment: Fyi a table can have only one primary key, by definition; you mean you have a *composite* primary key on `id, code`

Comment: Your sample INSERT should be doing `VALUES ((2, 'E', 50), (2, 'F', 50))`, right? You have `VALUES ((2, 'D', 50), (2, 'E', 50))` and that doesn't match your actual or desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question to ask yourself:  what is duplicated to make your `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause take effect.

Before your query you have a PK with value (2,D). And your insert specifies `VALUES ((2, 'D', 50), (2, 'E', 50))`.

So your INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE finds that record and updates it for  the first tuple in the statement.

But it inserts the second tuple because that one doesn't contain a duplicate key. Its key is 2,E.  And it doesn't touch your 2,C row at all.

It sounds to me like you need to work out your business rules in a bit more detail. If the business operation you do with that UPDATE statement you showed us actually means "remove all existing rows with id=2 and replace them with these rows" then you can't use MariaDB / MySQL database constraint operations to do that. You'll need to explicitly do a delete then insert operation.

You may be able to work out a way to somehow avoid deleting rows if they already exist, and rather just update them. But I doubt a trigger is the way to do that. If you can get it to work, it will be complex -- complex enough to make the next person working on your code to say rude things about you.

Triggers only examine the rows being inserted, updated, or deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I am now seeing multiple issues with what I originally thought could have be a viable approach. Thanks for helping me avoid going down a poor path lol.

Comment: One question @O. jones - If the FOR EACH STATEMENT were available in MariaDB could this approach have been entertained? 

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-limitations/#:~:text=Triggers%20are%20always%20executed%20for,mysql%2C%20information_schema%20or%20performance_schema%20database.

Comment: I don't know for sure; it depends on the operations allowed within a trigger FOR EACH ... I strongly believe that business rules like yours should be explicitly implemented by code, rather than buried in side-effects. (All triggers are side effects.) Plus triggers can make query performance unpredictable.